# Ellipsis expansion in nested functions: Error "'...' used in an incorrect context"

Tags: r, function

I have a very simple piece of code that produces:

```
afun <- function(a) {
  return(bfun(...))
}
bfun <- function(...) {
  return(a + 1)
}

> afun(1)
Error in afun(1) : '...' used in an incorrect context
```

But what R doesn't like here?

Comment: How can `afun` pass `...` to `bfun`, when `...` isn't defined in `afun`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your function `afun`:

```
afun <- function(a) {
  return(bfun(...))
}
```

the `...` is simply an argument (with no default value), just like any other. It doesn't mean "automatically suck up all arguments passed to the parent function". It just as if you had defined `bfun` as:

```
bfun <- function(b) {
  return(b + 1)
}
```

and then tried to do:

```
afun <- function(a) {
  return(bfun(b))
}
```

In order for `a` to be passed on to `bfun`, you either have to gather that argument yourself using something like `match.call`, or you have to hard code it (e.g. `return(bfun(a))`), or you have to use `...` as an argument (and the only argument) to `afun`.

Typically, `...` is used for passing *additional* arguments on to a subsequent function.

Comment: I've tried to use `...` as the only argument of `afun` (`afun <- function(...) { }`), but it still does not pass variable `a` to the `bfun`. I had to include `a` in `bfun` explicitly: `bfun <- function(a)`. So, I can't make it `bfun <- function(...)` this way?

Comment: @Anton That's right. If you defined `bfun <- function(a) a+1` then it would work. But if the only argument to a function is `...` then that function won't _automatically_ unpack the arguments in `...`. `...` is handed off to subsequent function calls, but those subsequent functions have to have _named arguments_ that match what's being passed in `...`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `afun` to return function with variable number of the arguments just return `bfun` as a return value of `afun`. In R these are called [closures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures)

This is what you get:

```
afun <- function(a) {
        print(a)
        function (b, ...){
                print(paste(b, ..., sep = " "))
        } 
}
```

The result is:

```
bfun <- afun("in afun body")    # "in afun body from print(a)

bfun("arg1")                    # "arg1" from  print(paste(b, ..., sep = " ")) 
bfun("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")    # "arg1 arg2 arg3" from  print(paste(b, ..., sep = " "))
```